# Rewrite shell script for windows (cygwin)

Tags: windows, bash, macos, shell, cygwin

I try to port a Shell script that works on mac to Windows.
i installed cygwin to make it as easy as possible but hardest Problem is the date command. Is there a package i can install that all date commands work?

If someoen can do it manually it would be ok, although a working cygwin Installation would be better for future scripts.

The problematic line (if someone can help):

```
dpat=`date -j -V+${i}d $ddpat "+%y.%m.%d"`
```

cygwin doesnt understand the -j and the -v Operator

Thank you very much in advance

Edit:

I dont exactly know what -j or -v do, i just guessed most of the script and was able to rewrite it. (I dont have a mac so i cant run it myself). Im sorry that it sounds so cryptic. I am not used to Shell/Macs. I thought it was something normal like "yeah on Mac date -v always does .....". I thought it was something like mkdir or so.

maybe this can help someone. some lines i was able to translate into bash by Trial and error. (I hope at least, since i can only try it when it fully works)
 and some guess work

Shell:

```
1. month=`date -v-40d +%Y-%m`
2. month=`date -v-${i}m +%Y-%m`
```

Bash:

```
1. month=`date --date="40 days ago" +%Y-%m`
2. month=`date --date="${i} month ago" +%Y-%m`
```

Are -v and -V the same? I dont know, here is maybe a Little more context:
(Where the line comes from)

```
while [ $dpat != $today ] ; do 
<copy some files with $dpat in filename>
dpat=`date -j -V+${i}d $ddpat "+%y.%m.%d"`
let i=i+1
done
```

And $today is defined as:

```
today=`date "+%y.%m.%d"`
```

Edit 2nd:
Ok colleague told me that -V is probably wrong and -v is the correct way

Comment: what are `-j` and `-V` supposed to do? my date (GNU coreutils) 8.21 doesn't have them either.

Comment: if i knew i might be able to rewrite it in bash, so i was hoping someone here knew..

Comment: check the [man date page for BSD](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?date)

Comment: is it possible to install These commands to cygwin somehow?

Comment: No, that's not possible. You still didn't say what these options are doing. If @fedorqui is right that this is BSD *date*, then -j can simply be omitted, but I still don't get the meaning of -V, because it is not documented on the page fedorqui mentioned. So, first please describe your problem fully, and then we can think of a solution.

Comment: i tried to give more Information in the edit. I dont exactly know what each step of the script does.